# Kill a python process from another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I need to be able to kill a python process from another process. Here is an example of how I'm doing it now:

In the 'main' process:

```
# Write the ProcessID to tmp file
with open('/tmp/%s' % self.query_identifier, 'w') as f: 
    f.write(str(os.getpid()))

try:
    cursor.execute('''very long query''')
except Exception:
    do_some_other_stuff()
    raise ConnectionError("There was an error completing this process")
```

And in the other process which 'kills' that process, I have:

```
pid = int(open('/tmp/%s' % self.query_identifier).read())
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

This works great. However, this entirely terminates the python process, and so it doesn't ever get to the `except` block of code. What would be a better way to do the above? For example, so that I can do the "kill" operation from another separate process without terminating the python program.

Comment: You can kill the other process with `signal.SIGINT` and set a signal handler for `SIGINT`.

Comment: @DYZ thanks for the suggestion -- could you please show how that would be done?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example).

Comment: @DYZ -- got it, changing `signal.SIGKILL` to `signal.SIGINT` was all I needed. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker program:

```
import signal

# Define and register a signal handler
def handler(signum, frame):
    raise IOError("Quitting on {}".format(signum))

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

try:
    while(True): # Imitate a long and winding road
        pass
except IOError:
    print("I've been killed!")
```

The supervisor program:

```
import os, signal
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```